# Best practice struts/jsp/i18n/resourceBundle

Tags: java, jsp, internationalization, struts2, resourcebundle

I am using Struts 2 and Apache tiles, and I'm new to both. I am trying to "clean" some existing sources that don't feel correct to me (tell me if I'm wrong).

I have the following structure :

- in a layout.jsp :

  ```
  <html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title><tiles:getAsString name="title" /></title>
      <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="content-size-and-border">
          <s:if test="display!='nomenu'">
              <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />
          </s:if>         
          <div id="maincontent">
              <tiles:insertAttribute name="maincontent" />
          </div>
      </div>

  </body>
  ```

The main content part displays various jsp/action depending on the item-menu clicked. 
The menu part uses some java code directly in the jsp to generate a number of sub-folders by iterating on a list.

```
<li class="highlight sousmenu"><a href="#"><s:text
    name="menu.demarrage" /></a>
    <ul class="niveau2">

        <%
        Locale language = (Locale) session.getAttribute("WW_TRANS_I18N_LOCALE"); 
        // the attribute (used by i18n struts interceptor) 
        // set in session when the user changes the language

        if (language == null)
            language = request.getLocale() ;
        // if the language was not changed, get the default Locale from browser

        User user = ((CustomUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getBpmUser();
            if (user != null) {
                for (Iterator iterator = user.getProcesses().iterator(); iterator
                        .hasNext();) {
                    String processToStart = (String) iterator.next();
                    String processPath = BpmUiConstantes.BPMUI_PROCESS_CONFIG_ROOT + "/" + processToStart ;
                    String processLib = "process." + processToStart + ".label";                              
        %>

        <li>
            <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/restricted/DemarrerProcessAvecTache?processName=<%=processToStart%>">
                <fmt:setLocale value="<%=language%>"/>
                <fmt:bundle basename="<%=processPath%>">
                    <fmt:message key="<%=processLib%>"/>
                </fmt:bundle>
            </a>
        </li>

        <%
                }   
            }
        %>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I was wondering if there was a better way to achieve the same result, without the java code in the jsp. Is it important to remove the java code from the jsp from a conception point of view ?

The application uses struts i18n interceptor for the language changes. Is there a way to have the menu use a struts i18n interceptor in some way?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the actual code, or some variation of it, that you are wanting to replace.

Comment: We would need to see the code. A JSTL forEach tag is another option.

Comment: Ok I added the piece of code I would like to replace. I'm going to check the JSTL forEach tag meanwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely look more into JSTL core (C tag to use foreach) and fmt(for the locale- language), with these two libraries you should be able able to safely remove the embedded java code into your page and use a more congruent/safe approach

Here is the oracle webpage to JSTL so you can have some reference

[JSTL Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/overview-summary.html)

Feel free to ask if you have any other questions.

Comment: Does it feel correct to have a java bean when the rest of the code is based on struts actions ?

Comment: The question is probably silly... I'm going to investigate a bit before I ask a new question.

Comment: Well consider your case where you already use Struts therefore yes it is correct.At least where I work (banking) it's a standard to integrate Struts with JSTL and EL

Comment: Okay then. However, my main purpose was to be able to use the i18n struts interceptor to detect and set the language for the menu as well. 

But since I won't be able to use an "action" I won't be able to use the i18n interceptor either. So in both cases (java code in jsp or not) I must set the Locale used by the bundle to the value of session.getAttribute("WW_TRANS_I18N_LOCALE") in a way or another.

Comment: +1 even though you linked to Oracle's website, which is one of the most un-friendly, un-intuitive websites ever. Do yourself a favor and just google JSTL.

Comment: well @StevenBenitez as an engineer I was trained to understand even the Oracle website, if you want to level-up look into IBM's one :))

Comment: @LucianEnache LOL! That sounds just as bad. :)

Answer (score 0):

I will add some piece of answer to the previous post :

There is no way to have this menu use a struts i18n interceptor and, above all, it is useless because ResourceBundle's Locale or fmt:bundle's Locale would not be set by this interceptor. It is necessary to specify explicitely the Locale (like I did in the code) => this part cannot be changed.

I'm still not sure about the importance of removing this java code from the jsp though.